# Values Tuples in C# 7 fails with MSBuild.exe when building the solution, not the project

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

We run Continuous Integration in Jenkins. And recently we decided to try out C# 7 Tuples in one of our web projects

The project compiles fine in Visual Studio, but when we send it to the build server it breaks.

`error CS8059: Feature 'tuples' is not available in C# 6.  Please use language version 7 or greater.`

I have tried everything, from updating nuget to banging my head against the wall.

I also installed the required nuget packages:

`Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
Install-Package System.ValueTuple`

Finally I had a break-through when I found out that I can publish each individual project, and it only breaks when building the entire solution.

That means it works, just not on the solution level. But WHY!?
I need to build the entire solution to run Unit Tests against our code base.

**So to recap:**

- msbuild MySolution.sln Fails!
- msbuild MyProject.csproj + PublishProfile works just fine.

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostic logging and compare.

Comment: Did you check language version in Project -> Properties -> Build -> Advanced -> Language Version ? It should be c# 6.0

Comment: Actually it should be C# 7, and that fixed it. I forgot to mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.

I changed the language version to C# 7, in both debug and release settings of the web project. In the project.csproj file.

I also installed the required nuget packages:

```
// Tells it to compile it according to the selected C# Language version
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers 
// Adds the value tuple support
Install-Package System.ValueTuple
// Tells it to use the Roslyn compiler
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Comment: I'd updated my debug build in VS to use the latest language version (latest minor rather than latest major) but hadn't updated the release build's configuration.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: For me that was stupid: I've updated the `<LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>` on my `.csproj` file, but I haven't realized that there was one individual settings for each building configuration. I wasted many hours because of that. Thanks to lead me to my solution. 